# How to Display Navigation Bread Crumb for SP Library and sub-folders

Tags: breadcrumb

I followed the steps presented in the following Q&A: [Folders in document libraries: how to navigate back up to parent folder (web part on page)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/97366/34390)

and I am unable to see the breadcrumb. If chrome is set to none, how will I see the breadcrumb? When I navigate to a library off the Main page, I still see no breadcrumb. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Food for thought...SharePoint provides a "navigate up" icon in the master page once enabled will display the breadcrumb functionality. Our organization recently migrated from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. In 2010 all user used the breadcrumb constantly, once we enabled to navigation up icon it was a big hit.

[Check it out...](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/)

Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]